# troubleshooting tcp/ip connection failure in my application

Tags: tcp, network-programming, winsock

I am having a desktop application which can talk to a server application using TCP/IP. It was working all these days but now we ran into an issue. The log message in the server shows that the socket is disconnected after a while, but we are able to exchange heart beat messages. When i ran the WhireShark tool i am getting this log which i dont know how to interpret.

[image]

The other thing is when i run this application in the LAN where the server is running it just works fine.

Please help me to understand what is happening in the network.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult for me to see the trace details but it looks like .218 is the client trying to connect to .135? If so, 218's connection attempts (SYN) are being immediately rejected by 135 (RST).  Normal 3-way TCP handshake should be SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK.

If the server is accepting requests from other hosts has some sort of firewall or the sort been setup to allow local LAN connections but disallow remote hosts?